# Using opencv to detect faces and play music at the same time

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, winsound

I wrote a program that will play a warning sound when a face is detected (play audio file)

However, the sound file will always start playing after  10 ~ 30 seconds when the detection condition is triggered.

And if it is removed from the conditional sentence and played as background music,there is no problem.
May I ask how to solve it?

Thanks!

THE code I use to play sound:

`winsound.PlaySound('1.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_ASYNC)`

The full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dlib
import cv2
import imutils
import winsound
import os
import multiprocessing
import winsound 
import time
from winsound import SND_ASYNC 
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

#chose camera

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
#change size
cap.set(cv2. CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2. CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360)

#Get the default face detector
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
#Load 68 feature point models according to the shape_predictor method, this method is a detector for facial expression recognition
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor( 'shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
#When the camera is turned on, each frame is detected
#pygame.mixer.init()
#mixer.music.load('incoming.mp3')
#mixer.music.play(-1)
#winsound.PlaySound('incoming.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME| winsound.SND_ASYNC  )
while(cap.isOpened()):
    #Read frame information
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #Detect faces
    face_rects, scores, idx = detector.run(frame, 0)

    #Retrieve the detection result
    for i, d in enumerate(face_rects):
      x1 = d.left()
      y1 = d.top()
      x2 = d.right()
      y2 = d.bottom()
      text = " %2.2f ( %d )" % (scores[i], idx[i])

      #Draw a rectangular area for detecting faces
      cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), ( 0, 255, 0), 4, cv2. LINE_AA)

      #Mark the face detection score and face direction sub-detector number
      cv2.putText(frame, text, (x1, y1), cv2. FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,
      0.7, ( 255, 255, 255), 1, cv2. LINE_AA)

      #play sound

      if scores[i]>0.3 and  idx[i]==0 :
        print(text)

        #pygame.mixer.pre_init(48000, 16, 2, 4096)
        winsound.PlaySound('incoming.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME| winsound.SND_ASYNC  )


    #Output to screen
    cv2.imshow( "Face Detection", frame)

    #If you press the ESC key, you exit
    if cv2.waitKey( 10) == 27:
       break

#Free memory
cap.release()
#Close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and the gprof2dot[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qr6P.png)

Comment: You need to understand how your task can be solved. Maybe you need to use multithreading because it is used well for I/O bound applications. Take a look at [this article](https://dev.to/nbosco/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python--63j).

Comment: Ok I will try it.Thk!